# Implement "not in" to select with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, notin

I have select:

```
select col1,
   case
    when col2 = 'AB' then col3
    else cols2
   end as colX,
col4,sum(col5) from table 1
where....
group by col1,
case
when col2 = 'AB' then col3
else cols2
end, col4
```

How to the where add something like: **col2 not in** ('AA','BB')?

I can't add col2 to my select, because I have couple of joins in my whole select statement.

Comment: What's wrong with `where <conditions> and col2 not in ('AA','BB')`?

Comment: Post your entire SQL query

Comment: when I did col 2 not in....I got error: Invalid column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the new condition in the `WHERE` clause. Also, if you switch to use a derived table, you don't have to write that `case` expression twice. (Easier to code without errors, easier to read, easier to maintain.)

```
select col1, colX, col4, sum(col5)
from
(
    select col1,
           case when col2 = 'AB' then col3
                else cols2
           end as colX,
           col4,
           col5
    from table1
    where...
      and col2 not in ('AA', 'BB')
) dt
group by col1, colX, col4
```